# Increase the font size of the axis description for ggbetweenstats with ggstatsplot

Tags: r

How can the text size for the axes be increased? for function ggbetweenstats and how can I increase the size of the equation?

Comment: Can you add your code and an example dataset?

Answer (score 0):

`{ggstatsplot}` returns `ggplot` objects, so you can use `{ggplot2}` functions to modify the plot further:

```r
library(ggstatsplot)
library(ggplot2)

ggbetweenstats(mtcars, am, wt) + 
  theme(axis.title = element_text(size = 30))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-10-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>